# Terminal not showing in Koding

Tags: koding

I'm running a VM on Koding, and my terminal is missing in action. How can I restore the hero to its glory?

[image: Koging without terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out when you click this top pane here:

[image: Screenshot]

You can open up a new terminal window, And then drag it below to the bottom pane so you can see both the code and the VM at the same time!